# How to make type alias to "a pointer to an array of const int"?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, alias, typedef

I am doing exercises on type alias (ex3.44 C++ Primer 5th ). 
The below code would make:

1. a type alias of a pointer to an array of const int, and
2. a type alias of a reference to an array of const int

However the result does not match expectation (see the comments). Why?

```
int main(){

  int ia[3] = {0, 1, 2};

  typedef const int (*cpa)[3];
  cpa g = 0;                    //(gdb) ptype g: type = int (*)[3]

  typedef const int (&cra)[3];
  cra h = ia;                   //(gdb) ptype h: type = int (&)[3]

  return 0;

}
```

When I remove the array, it works as expected. See below code:

```
int main(){

  int i = 42;

  typedef const int* cp;
  cp e = &i;                    //(gdb) ptype e: type = const int *

  typedef const int& cr;
  cr f = i;                     //(gdb) ptype f: type = const int &

  return 0;
}
```

One last thing,  how to rewrite the alias definition if to use the "using" keyword?

Comment: Why is it not what your expect?

Comment: @Joseph Mansfield the const is missing

Comment: Those are right, and `using` makes it even easier because you don't need the name in the middle of the mess. By the way, you can check at compile-time, too. `const int arr[3]; static_assert(std::is_same<cpa, decltype(&arr)>::value, "");`

Comment: @chris But the "const" is missing if with array

Comment: How you end up to the conclusion that `const` is missing

Comment: @40two I check the result's type with "ptype", and it shows `int (\*)[3]`; I was expecting an `const int (*)[3]`

Comment: `const int (&cra)[3]` is a reference to an array of constant `int`s of size 3, it's not a constant reference to an array of `int`s.

Comment: @40two But the second code snippet(the one without array) gives `const int &`. which is a bit confusing.

Comment: @user3701346 It shows `const int (*)[3]` and `const int (&)[3]` for me. What version of gdb are you using? I have 7.7

Comment: @chris thanks for the tip (I haven't seem this function/macro before). I tried out and it passes. So I assume that cpa is indeed `const int (*)[3]`. Strangely "gdb ptype" mis-print the result

Comment: @JosephMansfield I am using gdb 7.4 for debian (with print pretty on).

Comment: @user3701346, If you mean `static_assert`, it's not a function, nor a macro, but a declaration (*static-assert-declaration*). If you mean `decltype`, it's a specifier. If you mean `std::is_same`, it's a type trait (just a struct with a `value` member basically).

Answer (score 1):

It's just the output of your version of `gdb` that is omitting the `const`. The `const` is still important. We can prove that with the following program which will not compile:

```
int main(){
  const int ia[3] = {0, 1, 2};

  typedef int (*cpa)[3];
  cpa g = 0;

  typedef int (&cra)[3];
  cra h = ia;

  return 0;
}
```

For me, with gdb 7.7, the output is as expected:

```
(gdb) ptype g
type = const int (*)[3]
(gdb) ptype h
type = const int (&)[3]
```

To rewrite these `typedef`s with `using`:

```
using cpa = const int (*)[3];
using cra = const int (&)[3];
```

You can see the pattern is just `using identifier =` followed by the declaration with the identifier missing.

Comment: Joseph, could you share whether you turned on any "print pretty" options?

Comment: @user3701346 If that means doing `enable pretty-printer` beforehand, it seems to have no effect.

Comment: wait. `cpa` is the type name, how can you print it?  I only did `ptype g` and `ptype h` which are the variables.

Comment: @user3701346 Same result.

Comment: @user3701346 I assume this was a bug that was fixed between version 7.4 and 7.7

Comment: Ok I am checking 7.7 out.

Comment: 7.7 still fails for me. `using` passed.

Answer (score 1):

You are being too trusting of gdb. It is omitting the 'const', for reasons I don't understand. You should verify the constness of the types in other ways. One way is to try to assign to g[0]. This will give you an error that includes a message like this:

```
error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘int’ to ‘const int [3]’
```

Right away that tells you that your problem is non-existent.

You can also use typeid to get the type from the compiler and print it. On VC++ this does the job trivially. With gcc you need to demangle the results to make them readable. The code below prints the type of g and g2, with and without the const.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <typeinfo>

#ifdef __GNUG__
#define DEMANGLE
#endif

#ifdef DEMANGLE
#include <cxxabi.h>
#endif

template <typename T>
const char* TypeName(const T& type)
{
#ifdef DEMANGLE
    int status = 0;
    // Convert the cryptic gcc name decorations to something
    // human readable.
    return abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(type).name(), NULL, NULL, &status);
#else
    return typeid(type).name();
#endif
}

int main(){

  int ia[3] = {0, 1, 2};

  typedef const int (*cpa)[3];
  cpa g = 0;                    //(gdb) ptype g: type = int (*)[3]
  typedef int (*cpa2)[3];
  cpa2 g2 = 0;                    //(gdb) ptype g: type = int (*)[3]

  typedef const int (&cra)[3];
  cra h = ia;                   //(gdb) ptype h: type = int (&)[3]

  printf("Type of 'g' is '%s'\n", TypeName(g));
  printf("Type of 'g2' is '%s'\n", TypeName(g2));

  //g[0] = 2; This fails to compile, thus proving that cpa/g have the correct type.

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Now I have an alternative way of type checking.